# Pymongo API TypeError: Unhashable dict

Tags: python, api, mongodb, pymongo

I'm writing an API for my software so that it is easier to access mongodb.

I have this line:

```
def update(self, recid):        
    self.collection.find_and_modify(query={"recid":recid}, update={{ "$set": {"creation_date":str( datetime.now() ) }}} )
```

Which throws `TypeError: Unhashable type: 'dict'`.

This function is simply meant to find the document who's recid matches the argument and update its creation_date field.

Why is this error occuring?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's simple, you have added extra/redundant curly braces, try this:

```
self.collection.find_and_modify(query={"recid":recid}, 
                                update={"$set": {"creation_date": str(datetime.now())}})
```

UPD (explanation, assuming you are on python>=2.7):

The error occurs because python thinks you are trying to make a set with `{}` notation:

> The set classes are implemented using dictionaries. Accordingly, the
>   requirements for set elements are the same as those for dictionary
>   keys; namely, that the element defines both __eq__() and __hash__().

In other words, elements of a set should be hashable: e.g. `int`, `string`. And you are passing a `dict` to it, which is not hashable and cannot be an element of a set.

Also, see this example:

```
>>> {{}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, brilliant! But why was that causing such a problem?

Comment: I've improved the answer, please check.