# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when update array in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, typeerror

I'm trying to write RESTful API web service. Using MongoDB, I have collection User like this:

```
{
    userId
    name
    passwd
    listMovie: [
        {
            videoId
            watchedTime
            status
        }
    ]
}
```

And I created an API url to add new movie item into the `listMovie` array. Example code:

```
movie = {
    'videoId': 3,
    'watchedTime': 155000,
    'status': False
}

self.userCollection.update_one({
    {'userId': user_id},
    {
        '$push': {
            'listMovie': movie
        }
    }
})
```

But this code raised an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` at line `'listMovie: movie'`. According to this link [pymongo api type-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674100/pymongo-api-typeerror-unhashable-dict), I know that `dict` type is not hashable. So how can I achieve my purpose?

I using Python and PyMongo to connect to database

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the first curly braces:

```
self.userCollection.update_one(
    {'userId': user_id},
    {'$push': {'listMovie': movie}},
)
```

[`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) first two arguments are `filter` and `update` which are two dicts. In your example, you add some extra curly braces, which causes Python to actually build a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) because of the set shorthand syntax:

```
my_set = {1, 2}  # set with elements 1 et 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. That is the point I didn't understand in the reference link I suggested. Your answer is clear to me.