# Python unhashable type 'dict' in multi level json array

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary, flask

I want to update my database in MongoDB but i have problem with my code giving an error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I give **tuple()** inside dictionary to fix `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I have try search the solution on the internet and stackoverflow but none of them could help me, can anyone give me the solution with simple explanation?

```
@app.route('/updateData', methods=['POST'])
def updateData():
    dataList = mongo.db.warehouse
    old_Data = {
        "name": "Pulo Gebang Warehouse"
    }
    new_Data =  {
                    "$set": {
                        "racks.$[i].rack_columns.$[k].rack_objects.$[j].items": 
                            tuple([
                                {
                                    "index": 4,
                                    "item": {
                                    "SKU": "HD 2179/3",
                                    "arrivalDate": "2019-10-22",
                                    "brand": "Philips",
                                    "maxQty": 30,
                                    "name": "Playstatus 10",
                                    "qty": 10
                                    }
                                }
                            ])

                    }
                }
    arrayFilter = {
        tuple([
            {
            "i.code": "A"
            },
            {
            "k.ObjectID": 0
            },
            {
            "j.index": 4
            }
        ])
    }
    dataList.update(old_Data, new_Data, arrayFilter, upsert=True)
    return "Update Success!"
```

Comment: You are creating a set not a dictionary print the type of it and see

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before when [accidentally creating a set literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674100/pymongo-api-typeerror-unhashable-dict) with `{}`.
See if this works:

```py
  arrayFilters = [ # no curly braces so Python doesn't think you're creating a set
            {
            "i.code": "A"
            },
            {
            "k.ObjectID": 0
            },
            {
            "j.index": 4
            }
   ])
   # double check the signature of update as well
   dataList.update(old_Data, new_Data, arrayFilters=arrayFilters, upsert=True)
```

Comment: it says : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arrayFilters'

Comment: gotcha - looks like you solved the `unhashable` issue by removing the set, but now you'll need to double check the `update` signature for the mongo-python library you're using. e.g. try making the third argument the dict `{ "arrayFilters": arrayFilters }` instead? Happy to take a look at the docs if you have a link.

Comment: Will probably also depend on the version of mongo you're using, since that update signature has changed iirc